# Overwriting value of field in file Python: String Object error

Tags: python, string, overwrite

To clarify and simplify: I have the following file

```
    0,Genre, Title, Rating, Likes
    1,Sci-Fi,Out of the Silent Planet, PG, 0
    2,Sci-Fi,Solaris, PG,0
```

the code below seeks to **INCREMENT** the number of likes for a particular film. I have managed to pull out the respective row (based on an parameter from a previous function), but I now need to know how to manipulate a value in a list and add to it.

So in the row (that has been read into a list) the current likes are as follows, the value being currently "0"

```
currentlikes=[row[4]]
```

The following, would change the value in the list to "2"

```
currentrow[0][4]=2
```

I want it however, to change the value stored in the respective field (in that row) by +1. I need to know how to re-write this code to make it work

```
currentrow[0][4]=[row[4]]+1
```

I also tried:

```
currentrow[0][4]=currentlikes+1
```

The error message was:

```
    currentrow[0][4]=currentlikes+1
    TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Comment: Not constructive - I do not know how to work with this string which is why I've asked the question. Also, for the record, likedfilms[x][3] = like works fine (it assigns the number). What I want to know however, is how to get it to convert to an integer and allow me to increment. i.e currentlikes+1

Comment: Well, now that's you've completely changed the question, my comment previous indeed does not apply any more. But as a note: The previous error message was quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in python, try

`likedfilms[x]=likedfilms[x][:2]+str(like)+likedfilms[x][3:]`

or

`likedfilms[x] = "%s%d%s" % (likedfilms[x][:2], like, likedfilms[x][3:])`

BTW, it's really weird that you use likedfilms before declaring it a few lines later :)

- ^^ [Note: I walked this comment back down below]*

Comment: I'm just going to check to see if that works. Could you clarify what you mean about my declaration? As far as I can see likedfilms is declared (as a list) in the code: likedfilms=[row[2]]
......and then it is used in the next line:  print("You have liked:", likedfilms)
?What do you mean it is used before it is declared...? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explain the logic in your code? What is it doing..I cannot follow. Also, it produces this error:  likedfilms[x]=likedfilms[x][:2]+like+likedfilms[x][3:]
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: Ok, on further perusing, I see that you're not really doing that.  the formatting confuzzled me and made me think you were using the value form a previous loop iteration.  "Carry on!" :)

Comment: thx for the feedback!  I have edited my answer to make the code work for int (and also added another answer just for fun)

Comment: That's not quite what I want. To keep it simple, all I'm looking to do is change the value in a list, but base the changed value on a value in the list itself and increment. So, if the value I want to change is currentrow[row[4]] .... currentrow[0][4]=2, would change the value of that field in that row to "2". I want it however, to change to whatever is in currentrow[row[4]]+1 (increment by +1). Any thoughts?

Comment: What makes you think this: currentlikes=[row[4]]   is zero?  it's actually a list containing zero.

Comment: try currentlikes=int(row[4]) to get an int

Comment: Thanks Joel. Tried that however, error: currentlikes=int([row[4]])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: why did you put extra [] in there?  you turned it into a list.  notice my above response has no brackets at all.

Comment: if this code ===>  currentrow[4] = str( int(currentrow[4]) + 1 )   <==== doesn't do the trick than i might be out of ideas.